# user be able to draw a line on a svg element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I have a svg element:

```
<svg id="map" width="500" heigh="500"> </svg>
```

I can append a new line in this `svg tag` using following code:

```
var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
newLine.setAttribute('x1', 100);
newLine.setAttribute('y1', 200);
newLine.setAttribute('x2', 200);
newLine.setAttribute('y2', 200);
$("#map").append(newLine);
```

if you take a look at the code above, you'll see I have hard coded coordinates and typed `x1,y1` and `x2,y2` myself.
It successfully draws a line inside the `svg` tag using provided coordinates.
Now what I need to do is, user must be able to draw the line himself. something like windows paint application where user draws a line.
User must be able to click inside svg and draw a straight line. so those coordinates must be provided dynamically based on user action.
How can I do this? I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Search about HTML Canvas jquery. you have to use canvas to draw lines or a signature.

Comment: Use events: on mouse down create a newLine and set the x1 and y1 attributes to the position of the mouse; also append the line. On mouse move set the x2 and y2 attributes  to the new position of the mouse